# ShareActionProvider не работает так как startActivity(intent)

Tags: android-studio, actionbar

В приложении на панель инструментов добавлен ShareActionProvider (кнопка "Поделиться"), который передает текст для отправки. На панели инструментов он почему-то не активен, при нажатии на кнопку "Поделиться" предлагаются всего два варианта: "Bluetooth" и "Обмен с окружением". Для контроля на панели инструментов добавил действие, которое выполняет ту же задачу, но напрямую через startActivity(intent), здесь вариантов много как и должно быть: электронная почта, СМС и т.д. Что я делаю не так при настройке ShareActionProvider?

```
'''
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        setShareActionIntent("---");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_create_order) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "---");
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void setShareActionIntent(String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема связана с разрешениями начиная с Android API30:
[Package visibility filtering on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility)
Помогает добавление следующего кода в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```